# Each irreducible representation is a subrepresentation of induced one

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm learning what irreducible representation is and need some examples. One of them is as follows:
Let $G$ be any group and $H$ - it abelian subgroup. How to prove that each irreducible representation of $G$ is a subrepresentation of someone, induced from one-dimensional representation of  $H$ (this is a problem in the problem sheet)?

Comment: Hint: All irreducible representations of $H$ are one-dimensional. Then use Frobenius reciprocity.

Comment: Could you give some details briefly?

Comment: Are you familiar with Frobenius reciprocity?

Comment: I saw the formula:)

Comment: That formula has as a special case that if $\psi$ is a constituent of $\chi_H$ then $\chi$ is a constituent of $\psi^G$ (where $_H$ means restriction and $^G$ means induction).

Comment: I almost understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Let's prove a more general fact: If $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup, then every irreducible representation $\rho$ of $G$ is a subrepresentation of a representation induced by an irreducible representation of $H$ (in the special case $H$ is abelian, every irreducible representation is $1$-dimensional). The proof below definitely works for finite groups (but maybe there are some issues if $G$ is infinite?)

Given $\rho: G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ a representation, we first note that $\rho$ is a subrepresentation of the regular representation $\rho_{\operatorname{reg}}$ of $G$. Now you can check that $\rho_{\operatorname{reg}}$ is induced by the regular representation of $H$, which I will denote it by $\theta$. So $\theta$ is the regular representation of $H$. Now decompose $\theta$ into irreducible representations $\theta_1, ..., \theta_{m}$ of $H$. Thus,
$$
\theta = \theta_{1} \oplus \theta_{2} \oplus \cdots \oplus \theta_{m}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta)= \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}\left(\theta_{1} \oplus \theta_{2} \oplus \cdots \oplus\theta_{m}\right)
$$
But $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}$ commutes with direct sums, so we get
$$
\rho_{\operatorname{reg}} = \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta)= \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{1}) \oplus \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{m})
$$
Now $\rho$ is contained in $\rho_{\operatorname{reg}}$, so that
$\rho$ is contained in $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{1}) \oplus \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus \operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{m})$.

But $\rho$ is irreducible! Thus, $\rho$ must be contained entirely in $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_{i})$ for some $i$. In other words, $\rho$ is a subrepresentation of some rep of $G$ induced by irreducible rep of $H$.

Comment: Yeah, for infinite groups all sorts of things need to be taken care of, though mostly the issue that the representations need no longer be completely reducible. Also, one then needs to be a bit careful with "which" induction is used, as there might be two choices, depending on whether you want a left or right adjoint to restriction.

Comment: By saying that $\rho$ must be entirely contained in $\Ind^G_H(\theta_i)$ for some $i$, do you mean "there exists some submodule of $\Ind^G_H(\theta_i)$ that is isomorphic to $\rho$", or that exactly "$\rho \subset \Ind^G_H(\theta_i)$"?

Comment: @zyy It has been a while since I had written this answer so please take what I say with a grain of salt, but I think that it is the second option: $\rho$ should be entirely contained inside $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\theta_i)$ for some $i$.

Comment: @Prism I am a student new to representation theory, so sorry if I fail to make myself clear. I will try to restate my question explicitly. Suppose $H \leq G$, $\rho_{reg}$ and $\theta$ are respectively regular representation of $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Let $\rho$ be a irreducible subrepresentation of $\rho_{reg}$. Given a decomposition $\theta = \oplus_1^m \theta_i$, the corresponding decomposition of $\rho_{reg}$ is $\rho_{reg} = \oplus_1^m \operatorname{Ind_H^G}(\theta_i)$. What I really want to figure out is, $\rho$ does not have to be exactly a subrepresentation of some $\operatorname{Ind_H^G}(\theta_i)$, but we can only say $\rho$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of some $\operatorname{Ind_H^G}(\theta_i)$, is it correct?

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood your question. Yes, what you wrote in your last comment is correct, I believe. I am not very good in representation theory, so hopefully someone with more authority can confirm your suspicion! I will tag @TobiasKildetoft since they are definitely more knowledgable.

Comment: @Prism Thank you. I just want to make sure I did not miss some important conclusion.