# Constructive proof that every irreducible representation of $G$ is contained in an induced representation of it's subgroup $H$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $H\leq G$. An exercise in Serre is to prove:

> Show that each irreducible representation of $G$ is contained in a representation induced by an irreducible representation of $H$.

I have seen a non-constructive proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614755/each-irreducible-representation-is-a-subrepresentation-of-induced-one).

Yet, my first instinct was to try to construct an irreducible representation of $H$ in the regular representation of $G$ that induces to the regular representation of $G$.

Here's what I tried:

Let $V = \bigoplus_{g\in G}\mathbb{C}e_g$ be the regular representation of $G$. Put $h = \sum_{h\in H} e_h$ and define $W = \mathbb{C} h$. Then for all $g\in H$, $gh = g\sum_{h\in H}e_h = \sum_{h\in H} e_{gh} = h$. Hence, $W$ is invariant under $H$ and thus $W$ is a subspace of $V$ that is also an irreducible representation of $H$. But, my computation to show that $W$ induces to $V$ seems to fail.

Is there a constructive proof of this claim?

Comment: Is Frobenius reciprocity constructive? It tells you that the irreducibles of $H$ with this property are exactly those occurring in the restriction of a given irreducible of $G$ to $H$.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't studied that yet.